# $routeparams parameter when specifying template in ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, routeparams

I'm trying to use an `ng-include` in a view that specifies a template.  It looks something like this:

```
<div ng-if="editing" ng-controller="testcontroller" ng-include="'/Content/Templates/Test.html'"></div>
```

The backing js for that template expects some routeparams, as does how it's set up in route provider:

```
.when('/Test/:param1/:param2',
{
    templateUrl: '/Content/Templates/Test.html',
    controller: 'testcontroller'
})
```

Is there a way for me to specify those parameters when I'm using the `ng-include`? or is this the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: Seems like the wrong way to go about it. Where do the params come from? If they come from the url, then just use the router. If they come from elsewhere, just put them in your controller.

Comment: They come from the URL, but this is an effort to reuse an existing template, and inject it into a separate page.  Perhaps a directive would be a better approach?